# Crash with android 4.0 tab swipe

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, swipe

I've added a new activity and set it as a tab swipe in navigation type.
So far so good, then when I swipe to another tab, it crash and gives me this error (but it shows me the layout at least):

```
01-11 15:01:45.342: D/AndroidRuntime(29447): Shutting down VM
01-11 15:01:45.342: W/dalvikvm(29447): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4208a930)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:352)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:347)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:692)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:875)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1539)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1422)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12633)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12583)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12583)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12583)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-11 15:01:45.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29447):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Switching tabs:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = null;           
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new AddExpense();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new AddIncomeSource();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }
```

The inner class for the tabs (each class for each tab):

```
public static class AddExpense extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public AddExpense() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_expense, null);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public static class AddIncomeSource extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public AddIncomeSource() {
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_income, null);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure position never goes above 1?

Comment: I'd guess its your fragment-making switch/case which goes wrong.
Try adding one of your fragments into the default and see if the crash goes away.

Comment: sorry for late replay, thanks a lot!
the problem was my switch case exactly as you said so i added a default fragment.